# Java convert String into fileObject

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I know how to convert it when the file is locally present.. But how to do it when the file is on remote server
Here i am talking about

> org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject

This is how it is done on local server-

```
public static FileObject changeStringToFileObject(String path) {
        FileObject file = null;
        LocalFileProvider provider = new DefaultLocalFileProvider();
        try {
            file = provider.findLocalFile(new File(path));
        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample url of the file in Remote Server ? how do you access it is it via http /ftp etc

Answer (score 2):

Well then you have to Use an FTP java library to first get hold of the File(i.e download it locally) before you can use it in you swing app.

check [Apache Commons Net Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//)

Check this link for a sample : [Java + Apache Commons Net: Read FTPFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java)

Comment: I know i am using FTP4j for same and VFSJFileChooser.. to change directory in VFSJFileChooser we need FileObject instance i have string name of the folder..What problem i am facing is how to convert that string into FileObject